# Design error in bootstrap templates

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, bootstrap-modal

I can not perform a double click on the button of a bootstrap template. It simply gives me text pointer when I take my cursor on that button. I can not perform a double click on it. How do I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Probably another control is overlapping it?

Comment: Also, why are you using visual studio 2010???

Answer (score 0):

Use **ASP Button** instead of an HTML button and add your bootstrap class like this

```
<asp:Button runat=server CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btn_Click">
```

Comment: I tried your asp button code,but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It should work because I am myself developing a website in Asp.Net using bootstrap. Or else go to .aspx page right click -> view code. On .cs page write the code for button:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     //your code
}
```

If you want to use Bootstrap it is much better to use Visual Studio 2015.